# Can't create table in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, create-table

I want to create a table with my own table name. But I receive a exception when I try to run it. So, what's wrong with this query?

```
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("create table @newtable (word nvarchar(100) not null, sample nvarchar(500))", con.getConnectionString()))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newtable", textBox3.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**upd**: the exception is:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005).
>   [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 14, Token in error = @newtable]
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Result SetOption options)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at ts_v0001.Login.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at *file path*: line 59

Comment: Any time you have a question about an exception it's pretty important to show us the exception.

Comment: You **cannot** parametrize table (or column) name(s) by using `@tablename` in SQL Server. You'll have to either specify a fixed table name, or build the SQL statement yourself, in C# code, and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL parser is expecting a table name, not a parameter. If you really need to parameterize it, make sure to sanitize the name first, then you can do SqlCeCommand("create table " + name + " (...columns...)"). [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173393.aspx) says: "Table names must comply with the rules for identifiers. The table_name must be unique within the database. A table_name can contain a maximum of 128 characters." Now it doesn't say much about the syntax of identifiers... If you make sure it only contains letters, you should be okay.